# Are there any consumable statistics regarding closed questions?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, api, statistics

I'm wondering if I can find out which question was closed in the least amount of time when compared to all questions that were closed. So, if we have a set of closed questions, can I find the question that was closed in the least amount of time?

Like say take the timestamp of the time of creation, subtract it from the time of close (if the time of close is a recorded event in a table) and then parse the results?

Is there an API that could provide such media?

Comment: Try either [data.se] or [api.se].

Comment: If nobody beats me to it, I'll even do the query myself, it looks like a quick one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Cupcake mentioned, there's the Data Explorer.

Although judging from your profile, you already know enough SQL to do it on your own, I went ahead and made the query myself since I was curious.

Link to query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/189418)

Code:

```
SELECT TOP 100 p.Id as [Post Link], p.CreationDate as [Create Date],
              p.ClosedDate as [Close Date]
  from Posts p
  where p.PostTypeId = 1 and DATEDIFF(DAY, p.CreationDate, p.ClosedDate) < 1
  order by p.ClosedDate - p.CreationDate asc
```

gets me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810728 as the top result, which was closed in just 12 seconds.

---

At @rene's egging, I decided to try to find the fastest-closed question that actually got 5 close votes (rather than getting closed by a moderator).

I made a slightly modified query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/166565/fastest-closed-questions-with-5-close-votes)

```
SELECT TOP 100 p.Id as [Post Link],
               p.CreationDate as [Create Date],
               p.ClosedDate as [Close Date]
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
AND p.Id in (SELECT PostId FROM Votes WHERE VoteTypeId = 6
             GROUP BY PostId
             HAVING COUNT(PostId) = 5)
AND DATEDIFF(DAY, p.CreationDate, p.ClosedDate) < 1
ORDER BY p.ClosedDate - p.CreationDate ASC
```

which when run gets me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497143/hard-drive-password-doesnt-work as the top result, which was closed in a slightly more pedestrian 58 seconds.

---

Caveat: Obviously, these records can change over time, but it also looks like deleted questions aren't counted in the query (which makes some sense; they are deleted after all)

Comment: Very nice, thanks for showing me this, will def. be using it to explore!

Comment: Hmmm, tagged java (I expected c or c++ ) but this is closed by Andrew Barber, a moderator. It would be nicer to see which question got closed the quickest by 5 community members... this is to challenge you to practice your sql skills ;-)

Comment: @rene It's a little late here, so I'll have to call it a day for now. I'll revisit this and add that one tomorrow as an addendum.

Comment: Don't feel obligated @DennisMeng ...

Comment: @rene Eh, I don't think of it as an obligation. I think of it as a chance to make a good answer better. :)

Comment: @rene I think questions that get closed very quickly by 5 community members (e.g. sub one minute) almost always are offensive or nonsense and deleted quickly as well. Therefore they won't appear in the data explorer results.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm aware of the shortcomings of SEDE...the outcome can only be an indication...It can still have value...

Comment: @rene I said "tomorrow", but I guess I really meant "6-8 weeks"

Comment: There always is an tomorrow also, in the next 6-8 weeks. Nice work!